# OpenCV Image Stitching with Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to develop an Image Stitching application in Java using the OpenCV library. When I run the code I wrote, I get an error like the one in the picture. Where am I making a mistake? Can you help me?

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.Feature2D;
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d;
import org.opencv.features2d.SIFT;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDMatch;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread;
import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imwrite;

public class OpenCV_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat image_left = imread("C:\\Users\\Osman\\IdeaProjects\\opencv_tutorial\\src\\panorama_image1.bmp");
        Mat image_right = imread("C:\\Users\\Osman\\IdeaProjects\\opencv_tutorial\\src\\panorama_image2.jpg");

        Feature2D detector = SIFT.create();

        MatOfKeyPoint key_points_1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfKeyPoint key_points_2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        Mat descriptors_1 = new Mat();
        Mat descriptors_2 = new Mat();

        detector.detect(image_left, key_points_1);
        detector.detect(image_right, key_points_2);

        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

        Mat output_image = new Mat();
        Features2d.drawMatches(image_left, key_points_1, image_right, key_points_2, matches, output_image);


        matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

        double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;
        List<DMatch> listMatches = matches.toList();

        for( int i = 0; i < listMatches.size(); i++ ) {
            double dist = listMatches.get(i).distance;
            if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
            if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
        }


        LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
        MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
        for(int i = 0; i < listMatches.size(); i++) {
            if(listMatches.get(i).distance < 2*min_dist) {
                good_matches.addLast(listMatches.get(i));
            }
        }

        goodMatches.fromList(good_matches);

        // Calculate the homograohy between the two images...
        LinkedList<Point> imgPoints1List = new LinkedList<Point>();
        LinkedList<Point> imgPoints2List = new LinkedList<Point>();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints1List = key_points_1.toList();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints2List = key_points_2.toList();

        for(int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++) {
            imgPoints1List.addLast(keypoints1List.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
            imgPoints2List.addLast(keypoints2List.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
        }

        MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
        obj.fromList(imgPoints1List);
        MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
        scene.fromList(imgPoints2List);

        Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, Calib3d.RANSAC,3.0);

        int imageWidth = image_right.cols();
        int imageHeight = image_right.rows();

        Mat Offset = new Mat(3, 3, H.type());
        Offset.put(0,0, new double[]{1});
        Offset.put(0,1, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(0,2, new double[]{imageWidth});
        Offset.put(1,0, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(1,1, new double[]{1});
        Offset.put(1,2, new double[]{imageHeight});
        Offset.put(2,0, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(2,1, new double[]{0});
        Offset.put(2,2, new double[]{1});

        // Multiply the homography mat with the offset.
        Core.gemm(Offset, H, 1, new Mat(), 0, H);

        Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
        Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);

        obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{0,0});
        obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{imageWidth,0});
        obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{imageWidth,imageHeight});
        obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{0,imageHeight});

        Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

        Size s = new Size(imageWidth *3,imageHeight*3);
        Mat img_matches = new Mat(new Size(image_left.cols()+image_right.cols(),image_left.rows()), CvType.CV_32FC2);


        Imgproc.warpPerspective(image_left, img_matches, H, s);


        int m_xPos = (int)(img_matches.size().width/2 - image_right.size().width/2);
        int m_yPos = (int)(img_matches.size().height/2 - image_right.size().height/2);
        Mat m = new Mat(img_matches,new Rect(m_xPos, m_yPos, image_right.cols(), image_right.rows()));

        // Copy img2 to the mat in the middle of the large result mat
        image_right.copyTo(m);


        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000000; // Milliseconds (1:1000000)
        //loadedImagesText.append("Stitching 2 images took " + elapsedTime + "ms\n");


        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int stepping = 6;

    }

}
```

When I ran the code, I expected the Image Stitching process to be successful, but I encountered an error that I did not understand.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmrUK.png)